# how to add toolbar menu on pyqgis using custom class with current QgsInterface?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, python-script-tool, toolbar

currently i want to add a qgis toolbar icon, which needs to be populated on the qgis window after certain process using custom class by overriding the current qgisinterface. But while running the code i got no issue on the code but the toolbar icon is not populating. Anyone can look at the code for related bugs.

```
class CustomMenuPlugin:
      def __init__(self, iface):
         self.iface = iface

      def initGui(self):
         self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar("CustomMenu")
         self.add_custom_menu()

      def add_custom_menu(self):
         custom_menu = QMenu("Custom Menu", self.iface.mainWindow())
         action1 = QAction("Action 1", self.iface.mainWindow())
         action1.triggered.connect(self.custom_action_triggered)
         custom_menu.addAction(action1)

         action2 = QAction("Action 2", self.iface.mainWindow())
         action2.triggered.connect(self.custom_action_triggered)
         custom_menu.addAction(action2)

         # You can add more actions as needed

         self.custom_menu_button = QAction("Custom Menu", self.iface.mainWindow())
         self.custom_menu_button.setMenu(custom_menu)
         self.toolbar.addAction(self.custom_menu_button)

      def unload(self):
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.toolbar, self.custom_menu_button)

      def custom_action_triggered(self):
         # Implement the logic for your custom actions here
         pass

  custom_menu_plugin = CustomMenuPlugin(self.obj_iface)
```

Comment: Either you haven't provided enough code in your example or your `initGui` function never gets called.

Comment: Also if your `self.obj_iface` is a `QgisInterface` object then your `unload()` function will raise error `TypeError: QgisInterface.removeToolBarIcon(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QToolBar'`

Comment: ok let me try it out.

Comment: Now the issue has been resolved after, passing the QgisInterface as a parameter instead a object refernce.